# failing to get jsonp response using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery

I want to invoke a rest service in another domain using Jquery ajax request.

My piece of code is :
ad1,city,sp,pc,cn will taken by getElementbyID.

```
url='http://admin:admin@*******:***/rest/arun_code/results.json'+'?Data.AddressLine1='+ad1+'&Data.City='+city+'&Data.StateProvince='+sp+'&Data.PostalCode='+pc+'&Data.Country='+cn;
   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: url,
       crossDomain: true,
       async: false,
       dataType: "jsonp",
       contentType: "application/json",
       jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
       success: function (data) {
           alert(data.success);
           alert(resultTemp.Output);

       }

   });

   jsonCallback = function(resultTemp){
       alert("In callback function");
       alert(resultTemp);
     };
```

In my web browser console I am getting this exception :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :  at results.json :1
```

With Chrome developer tools I can read the response, that is perfectly fine :

```
{"Output":[{"Latitude":"43.643286156655485","Longitude":"-79.37559537260091"}]}
```

I am not getting any alerts with response, i want to get the output as an alert and accessible..

my server output is json and I have to use jsonp for cross domain request, How to get the access on the output????
please help me.

Thank you

Comment: Are you the provider of the REST service?

Comment: Could use php's CURL to grab the json to your server then parse with jquery.

Comment: REST service is in another server.
Both are different domains.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the response is not JSONP. Wikipedia has a very good explanation as to how JSONp works:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

i.e.

```
{
    "Name": "Foo",
    "Id": 1234,
    "Rank": 7
}
```

**becomes**

`jsonCallback({"Name": "Foo", "Id": 1234, "Rank": 7});`

You can't just do a normal AJAX request at an existing server and expect it to respond accordingly. You need to configure the server to respond with the appropriate JSONp format.

Comment: Thank you for ur reply,
What I have to do now to get the response?

Comment: If the request must be cross-domain, you need to either modify the server-side to return JSONp (this depends entirely on the server setup), or else to put your own server in between as a proxy

Comment: Sorry, i cant change the output format of my server. It will give only two types either xml or json.

Any other idea??

Comment: @Arun Another way would be to create your own web service, which acts as a proxy, downloads the JSON required and formats it for a JSONp response.

Comment: Thank you ..
But i have less knowledge in web services, i think its lengthy process..
Can u please give some more brief about the solution?

Comment: @Arun Yes, it is fairly involved. You would create a web service in ASP/PHP/Similar, download your .json file on *this* server, then wrap the response in the `jsonCallback()` and send it back to the client. In your Javascript, instead of calling to the original server, you call to your own web service. Too detailed to go into in a comment on SO :)

Comment: @ Blade0rz:
Thank you..I will try to do that.
I have a doubt, can we use jQuery.getJSON() insted of ajax??

Comment: On a side note: If your proxy service is deployed on the same server as your app you no longer have to worry about cross-domain requests. Your proxy can simply forward the request/response.